# Hover over child and change parent background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have my html code:

```
<div id="bot-bar">
    <nav class="main-nav" id="main">
        <a id="home" href="/">Home</a>
        <a id="events" href="events.php">Events</a>
        <a id="news" href="news.php">News</a>
        <a id="ranks" href="ranks.php">Ranks</a>
        <a id="media" href="media.php">Media</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

When I hover over an `<a>` tag, it should change the color of the `bot-bar` div. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var botBar = $('#bot-bar');

botBar.find("a").hover(function(){
   botBar.css({backgroundColor: "red"});      // mouseenter event
}, function(){
   botBar.css({backgroundColor: "green"});    // mouseleave event
});
```

Or somewhat shorter (less performant but to show some possibilities):

```
$('#bot-bar a').hover(function( ev ){
   $(this).closest("div").css({background: ev.type=="mouseenter"?"red":"green"});
});
```

To get the currently hovered element background:

```
var botBar = $('#bot-bar');
var botBarBg = botBar.css("background-color");

botBar.find("a").hover(function(){
   var bg = $(this).css("background-color");
   botBar.css({backgroundColor: bg});      // mouseenter event
}, function(){
   botBar.css({backgroundColor: botBarBg});    // mouseleave event
});
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/diyowu/2/edit)***

Comment: How do I set the background color of `#bot-bar` to the background color of the `a` tag?

Comment: The shorter version is not a best practice concerning performance, since it has to find the closest div every time.

Comment: @Vitox exactly. Actually it's not performant to use jQ at all (But it's a terribly awesome time-savior!)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan While I agree about the performance drawback inherent  to jQ, I try to minimize its impact to the minimal as possible. I think that will never be able to don't use jQ at all, but in this particular case, I really dislike to have a loop fired every time, a event happens... Your other approaches are perfect, but the minimized version is the kind of thing you really should avoid (or in cases where other programers can't even see the performance problem, We that can, should not suggest such approaches). Mathematically is (jQ drawback) * ((<a> count) * its events).

Comment: @Vitox the event will be assigned inside the jQuery's `selector` or `Sizzle` function looping all the selector elements. Nothing to worry about. That's how Events on multiple elements work after all; assigned at parse(+ready) time (in this case). The only concern is the *find-my-parent!*, but that will happen only on hover, when that UI action takes place, again nothing to worry about. Your suggestion is good, but your math is a bit exagerated :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  Are you sure? Because as far as I know, your selector returns a collection of <A>s, then a loop iterate for each of this As, adding your function to the listener. jQ doesn't alocate automatically the last "closest" for other listeners. So, every time you hover an <A>, you're firing the function. Every time you fire the function, jQ has to search for the parent.  So (jQ drawback) * ((<a> count) * each time it fires hover and leave events), isn't correct?

Comment: @Vitox yes, that's what I said. Everything inside a `mouseenter mouseleave` (AKA `$.hover()`) will in any case be triggered only upon a User Action, what IS performant is the use of `$(this)`, the less performant is: *"hey you, now go find your parent DIV"* (`.closest("div")`). But hey, this will occur only once one hovers an element. The event is waiting in the window Events queue stack, so I repeat, nothing to worry. It's just a simple 1 or 2 step DOM traversal (more expensive than finding a children, but hey... :)

Comment: @Vitox also, `$('#bot-bar a')` is less performant than using `.find("a")` but here we're talking about some UI action that will rarely occur, so I'm fine with leaving the example intact. Hope it makes sense. Thanks though for your great suggestions and concerns I really appreciate that!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just think that we have different concerns about performance in milliseconds (haha). I don't care if it takes 10 milliseconds once that page loads, but every time I enter and leave the element... It's so much logical to me that you really should avoid a loop if it's just declare a variable to reuse, that that approach make me uncomfortable. But it's just a perfection problem... That put aside, great answer!  :)